# Jquery Including several spans using insertAfter inside a div

Tags: jquery, css, append, fotorama, insertafter

I am doing a controlpanel below fotorama.
Everything is working, except that I am not able to add the spans for the buttons created in the jquery into a div. I am using insertAfter as it needs to be After the fotorama_nav_wrap.
I have been playing with append, but I can´t manage it. 
I want to have the buttons in this div:

This is the jquery:
    // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
    var $fotoramaDiv = jQuery('.fotorama_custom').fotorama();

```
// 2. Get the API object.
var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');


if (jQuery('.fotorama_custom__arr').length > 0) {
    jQuery('.fotorama_custom__arr').remove();
}

jQuery("<span class='fotorama_custom__arr--prev'>       <</span>").insertAfter(".fotorama__nav-wrap");
jQuery("<span class='fotorama_custom__arr--next'>></span").insertAfter(".fotorama__nav-wrap");
jQuery("<span class='fotorama_custom__buttonplay'>P</span>").insertAfter(".fotorama__nav-wrap");
jQuery("<span class='fotorama_custom__buttonstop'>S</span>").insertAfter(".fotorama__nav-wrap");
jQuery('.fotorama_custom__arr--prev').click(function () {
fotorama.show('<');
});
jQuery('.fotorama_custom__arr--next').click(function () {
    fotorama.show('>');
});
$(function () {
    var $fotorama = $('#start-n-stop'),
            fotorama = $fotorama.data('fotorama'),
            $thumbBorder = $('.fotorama__thumb-border', $fotorama),
            thumbBorderColor = $thumbBorder.css('border-color'),
            thumbBackground = $thumbBorder.css('background'),
            $start = $('#start'),
            $stop = $('#stop');
            etc.
```

Updated with solution:
It works now, I changed the insert.After to append, and then appended the div:

```
 $('.fotorama') // Initialize .fotorama() .each(function () { 
    $('.fotorama__nav', this).after( 
    $(this) .next('.fotorama-control') .
    show() ); }); $('.fotorama-control').append
    ("<span class='fotorama_custom__arr--prev'><</span>"); 
    jQuery('.fotorama_custom__arr--prev').click(function () { 
    fotorama.show('<');
```

Comment: Have you checked with dev tools - are the new objects there at all?

Comment: code outside of `$(function(){` may be executing before the elements exist

Comment: Not sure I understand, the script works perfectly, the only problem is that they does not appear inside the div fotorama-control.
The div is in yellow, I need to have them inside in order to style the div.
Thanks,
Here is what I have so far in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72jTR/139/

Comment: I have included the script inside $(function(){ and does not make any difference. Can be see on the jsfiddle page

Comment: I have checked in dev tools and the objects are as per dev tools:
after <div class="fotorama__nav-wrap></div>
and before this div:
<div class="fotorama-control">
  <div id="barra"></div></div>
I want them inside fotorama-control or the added div barra

Comment: It works now, I changed the insert.After to append, and then appended the div:
 $('.fotorama')
  // Initialize
  .fotorama()
  .each(function () {
    // Append the #fotorama-control to the fotorama
    $('.fotorama__nav', this).after(
      $(this)
        .next('.fotorama-control')
        .show()
    );
  });
         $('.fotorama-control').append("<span     class='fotorama_custom__arr--prev'><</span>");
    jQuery('.fotorama_custom__arr--prev').click(function () {
        fotorama.show('<');